# Is there a option to use gradient as fillcolor in geoShapes?

Tags: javascript, here-api, here-maps-rest

I need to use a gradient as fill color in an geoShape on a here map.
Is there any option to do this?

if i use something like this:

```
// init HereMap
let platform = new H.service.Platform({
      'app_id': '111',
      'app_code': '111-111',
      useCIT: true,
      useHTTPS: false
    });

let defaultLayers = this.platform.createDefaultLayers();

let map = new H.Map(
      this.mapElement.nativeElement,
      defaultLayers.terrain.base,
      {
        zoom: 6,
        center: { lat: 51.22172, lng: 6.77616 }
      }
    );

let behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(this.map));
let ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(this.map, defaultLayers, 'de-DE');

// set geoShape style
 let customStyle = {
      strokeColor: 'none',
      fillColor: 'linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%)',
      lineWidth: 10,
      lineCap: 'square',
      lineJoin: 'bevel'
    };

// Create a rectangle and pass the custom style as an options parameter:
    var rect = new H.map.Rect(new H.geo.Rect(53.5, 12.5, 51.5, 14.5),
      { style: customStyle });

// Add the rectangle to the map:
    this.map.addObject(rect);

// Zoom the map to fit the rectangle:
    this.map.setViewBounds(rect.getBounds());
```

i get only a black object ...

thanks your help :)

Comment: Please provide a full working example. Here's why: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation please use the color name or RGB format to enter fillcolor values.

```
var customStyle = {
  strokeColor: 'black',
  fillColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)',
  lineWidth: 10,
  lineCap: 'square',
  lineJoin: 'bevel'
};


**fillColor**   The color with which a shape's area will be filled (ignored for polylines)
```

https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/dev_guide/topics/geo-shapes.html